# AVR ATtiny814 program executes first function, ignoring main

Tags: c, linker, avr

I'm trying to write software for an ATtiny814 (tiny avr 1-series) microcontroller, but I encounter a strange problem: whatever the first function in main.c is, gets executed and the remaining code gets ignored - including the `main()` function.

I'm using the avr-toolchain from the Arduino IDE on macOS, but I'm not using the IDE, I just added the *bin/* directory of the avr-toolchain to the PATH variable. The code just compiles fine without errors or warnings. Using pyupdi I can successfully flash the program to the chip, and again it works fine - except that only code from the first function in the main.c is executed.

`Makefile:`

```
TARGET      = project
CLOCK       = 2000000 # configured in main
SOURCES     = main.c

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
COMPILE = avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=$(CLOCK) -D__AVR_DEVICE_NAME__=attiny814 -D__AVR_DEV_LIB_NAME__=tn814

# compiling and linking, target is the finished hex file
all: $(TARGET).hex

# compile source files to object files
.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@

# link the object files together
$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET).elf

# convert elf file to hex file
$(TARGET).hex: $(TARGET).elf
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .data -j .text $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET).hex $(TARGET).elf $(OBJECTS)
```

**Example 1**

`main.c:`

```
#include <avr/io.h>


void test1() {
    // turn on PB1
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN1_bm;
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
}


int main() {
    // disable protection to configure clock frequency
    CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
    
    // configure CPU frequency
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc; // use 20 MHz internal clock as source
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = CLKCTRL_PDIV_10X_gc | CLKCTRL_PEN_bm; // divide by 10 and enable divider
    
    // turn on PB0
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN0_bm;
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN0_bm;
    
    // main program loop
    while(1) {};
    return 0;
}
```

Here, only `test1()` is executed, as only PB1 turns on.

**Example 2**

`main.c:`

```
#include <avr/io.h>

// prototype
void test1();


int main() {
    // disable protection to configure clock frequency
    CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
    
    // configure CPU frequency
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc; // use 20 MHz internal clock as source
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = CLKCTRL_PDIV_10X_gc | CLKCTRL_PEN_bm; // divide by 10 and enable divider
    
    // turn on PB0
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN0_bm;
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN0_bm;
    
    // main program loop
    while(1) {};
    return 0;
}


void test1() {
    // turn on PB1
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN1_bm;
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
}
```

Here, `main()` gets skipped and again `test1()` is executed, turning PB1 on.

**Example 3**

`main.c:`

```
#include <avr/io.h>


void test0() {
    // turn on PB0
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN0_bm;
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN0_bm;
}


void test1() {
    // turn on PB1
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN1_bm;
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
}
```

No main function at all. No compiler errors. Only `test0()` gets executed and PB0 turns on.

I have no clue whats going on here. Btw, using the same avr-toolchain setup, I can write software for an ATtiny841 (it's a different architecture/series) as expected.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you don't link the startup code, which calls `main()`. Otherwise you would get linker errors without a `main()`. -- You can give the linker an option to generate a map file. This will tell you which functions are there and where they are placed.

Comment: 1) the `main()` function never calls the sub function: `test1()`  2) the linker statement: `CLOCK       = 2000000 # configured in main` is not correct.  The makefile only recognizes `#` when it is the first thing on the line

Comment: since the target hardware does not have an OS, the makefile must include the startup software in the final executable AND/or there needs to be a 'linker.cmd' file that  dictates where in memory each item in the executable is placed in memory

Comment: I don't really understand... how do I link the startup code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a solution: When I compile it as described here https://github.com/vladbelous/tinyAVR_gcc_setup#example-of-compiler-usage, it works.

So in my case:

```
avr-gcc -c -Os -DF_CPU=2000000 -mmcu=attiny814 main.c
avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny814 -o main.elf main.o
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -j .rodata -O ihex main.elf main.hex
```

Fixed `Makefile`:

```
TARGET = project
MCU = attiny814
DEVICE = tiny814
# clock settings applied in main.c
CLOCK = 2000000
PROGRAMMER = /dev/tty.usbserial-A50285BI

SOURCES = main.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
COMPILE = avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=$(CLOCK) -mmcu=$(MCU)

# compiling and linking, target is the finished hex file
all: $(TARGET).hex

# compile source files to object files
.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@

# link the object files together
$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET).elf

# convert elf file to hex file
$(TARGET).hex: $(TARGET).elf
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -j .rodata -O ihex $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex

# flash (call make flash), requires pyupdi installed
flash: $(TARGET).hex
    python3 -m updi.pyupdi -d $(DEVICE) -c $(PROGRAMMER) -f "$(shell pwd)/$(TARGET).hex"

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET).hex $(TARGET).elf $(OBJECTS)
```